# Webpack: Missing script: "build". Как решить проблему?

Tags: node.js, webpack, npm

Пишу на быструю руку. Возникла проблема, не могу собрать файлы. Не работаю с `node.js`, но это нужно. Кто сталкивался с данной проблемой, объясните пожалуйста, как решить её?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У Вас в package.json отсутствует скрипт `build`. Чтобы указанная команда работала, в разделе "scripts" должно быть соответствующее описание.

Comment: судя по картинке тут и `package.json` отсутствует. А что вы ожидаете от сборки и зачем? Вообще, похоже что вам надо просто открыть `index.html` в браузере